# Выравнивание блоков

Tags: css3, html, html5, css

Есть такая структура [тыЦ](http://hkar.ru/zLJz)

```
<div class="top">
    <div class="label">
        Приветсвуем тебя на сайте <span>super site</span>
        <div class="search-button"><span></span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="user-bl">
        Вход на сайт
    </div>
</div>

.top{
background: $topBg;
height: 50px;
position:relative;
border-top: 2px solid $mainGreen;
border-bottom:1px solid $cSilver15;
& .label{
    position:relative;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding:0 50px 0 100px;
    line-height: 50px;
    color: $cSilver10;
    font-size: 20px;
    background:red;
    & span{
        font-family: Calibri;
        font-size: 24px;
        color: $topLabel;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }
    & .search-button{
        position: absolute;
        width: 70px;
        top:0;
        right: -70px;
        bottom: 0;
        & span{
            position: absolute;
            top:0;bottom: 0;left:0;right:0;
            background:url(../img/sprite.png) no-repeat 18px 9px
        }
    }

}

& .user-bl{
    float: right;
    line-height: 50px;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0 15px;
}}
```

Нужно блок приветствия заставить пристыковаться в упор к блоку входа на сайт, при этом не использовать фиксированную ширину или javascript. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.top{ display: flex; flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;}

& .label{  flex-grow: 2;}

& .user-bl{
   align-self: flex-start;
}}
```

http://codepen.io/DimaelVertigo/pen/ogaWWE